# How can I commit a large update 1000 records at a time?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, commit

Is it possible to commit update / delete once in 1000 record even though my inner select query returns more rows say 25K?

```
update sometable1
  set somecolumn
where somewhere in (select somewhere from sometable2);
```

Literally I wanted to commit once 1000 rows updated...

Comment: Which RDBMS please (SqlServer, MySql etc)? Native update statements should be atomic, meaning that all records will be committed upon completion. You'll need to implement a manual batch + commit strategy.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? But your commit should be dictated by your business logic.

Comment: its Oracle 11G. This SQL is not going to run with application. need this for updating the tables directly

Comment: Then just run it, and commit at the end. Doing frequent commits is almost always **slower** than doing a single commit at the end. Btw: if `sometable2.somewhere` can contain `null` values, your update is not going to work as you expect it.

Comment: there is no need to do that. That's way Oracle has not support for it. A single atomic will be faster. Forget patterns which are necessary on other databases. Also the query should be `set somecolumn = somevalue`;

Answer (score 3):

T.Kyte has beautifully explained the myth about frequent commits [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022):

> There is only one thing that dicates when you commit -- when is your
>   transaction complete?  Then you commit, period.

- leads to **ORA-1555** and the failure of your process.
- throws **transactional integrity** out the window.
- forces you to **WAIT** for a sync write to the file system every time

Frequently commiting in the mistaken belief that you are conserving resources or making things go faster only does this for you:

- slows you down.
- doesn't conserve any resources, in fact, it consumes more (you generate MORE redo)
- seriously puts into question the integrity of your data

Comment: While I agree in >> 95% of the cases, there is one marginal edge case I've found in Sql Server, which is to do bulk merges into existing read-heavy tables (such as a CQRS read store), where a smaller commit size < 5000 rows will avoid lock escalation to a Table Lock. Transactions aren't important here, but continuous reads (with READ COMMITTED isolation) are. But different RDBMS. And in fact, this may be an indication of a need for a non "C" CAPs data store, e.g. NoSql would be better suited.

Comment: @StuartLC Oracle never escalates locks.